# mysql group by error

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

below is a query I'm using

```
SELECT 
  `names`, sum(cashin.amount) as amountin, 
  sum(cashout.amount) as amountout, 
  (sum(cashin.amount) - sum(cashout.amount)) as total 
FROM (`client`) 
INNER JOIN `cashin` ON `cashin`.`clientid`=`client`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `cashout` ON `cashout`.`clientid`=`client`.`id` 
WHERE (sum(cashin.amount) - sum(cashout.amount)) < 0 
GROUP BY `client`.`id`
```

Problem is I get an error:

> `Invalid use of group function`

Replacing the function in where clause with field alias `'total'` I still get an error:

> `Unknown column total`

How can this query be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`, and put the `GROUP BY names` clause instead of `GROUP BY id` before the `HAVING` clause like so:

```
SELECT 
  `names`, 
  sum(cashin.amount) as amountin, 
  sum(cashout.amount) as amountout, 
  (sum(cashin.amount) - sum(cashout.amount)) as total 
FROM client
INNER JOIN `cashin` ON `cashin`.`clientid`=`client`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `cashout` ON `cashout`.`clientid`=`client`.`id` 
GROUP BY names
HAVING (sum(cashin.amount) - sum(cashout.amount)) < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
SELECT 
  `names`, 
  sum(cashin.amount) as amountin, 
  sum(cashout.amount) as amountout, 
  (sum(cashin.amount) - sum(cashout.amount)) as total 
FROM client
INNER JOIN `cashin` ON `cashin`.`clientid`=`client`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `cashout` ON `cashout`.`clientid`=`client`.`id` 
GROUP BY names
HAVING total < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using a `HAVING` clause, you can wrap your query in a `SELECT` statement and then place the filter in a `WHERE` clause:

```
select names,
  amountin,
  amountout,
  total
from
(
  SELECT 
    `names`, 
    sum(cashin.amount) as amountin, 
    sum(cashout.amount) as amountout, 
    (sum(cashin.amount) - sum(cashout.amount)) as total 
  FROM client
  INNER JOIN `cashin` ON `cashin`.`clientid`=`client`.`id` 
  INNER JOIN `cashout` ON `cashout`.`clientid`=`client`.`id` 
  GROUP BY names
) src
where total < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you make an alias of this

```
   (sum(cashin.amount) - sum(cashout.amount)) as total
```

as total so why u dont use it here ?

```
  WHERE (sum(cashin.amount) - sum(cashout.amount)) < 0
```

replace it by

```
     WHERE total < 0
```

and this

```
 FROM (`client`)
```

just use

```
  FROM `client`
```

and this

```
  (sum(cashin.amount) - sum(cashout.amount)) as total  // line 4
```

replace it by

```
   (amountin - amountout) as total
```

and it will work good for you.